# How to get the last indexpath of a uicollectionview?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, nsindexpath

I want to get the last indexpath of a uicollectionview.

I tried this:

```
 NSInteger section = [self numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:self.collectionView] - 1;
NSInteger item = [self collectionView:self.collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:section] - 1;
NSIndexPath *lastIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:item inSection:section];
```

But couldn't find the last indexpath of an uicollectionview .

Any suggestions,
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The code looks OK. What do you mean by "couldn't find the last indexpath of an uicollectionview"? What is the output of `NSLog(@"%@", indexPath)`? And what is the expected output?

Comment: NSInteger section = [_collectionView numberOfSections] - 1 ;
    NSInteger item = [_collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:section] - 2 ;
    NSIndexPath *lastIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:item inSection:section] ;  this worked fine for me...  thanks for your comment

Comment: why don't you create the index-path from your _model_ instead? that would feel more natural rather than messing with the _view_.

Answer (score 5):

```
NSInteger lastSectionIndex = [tableView numberOfSections] - 1;
NSInteger lastRowIndex = [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:lastSectionIndex] - 1;

// Now just construct the index path
NSIndexPath *pathToLastRow = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:lastRowIndex inSection:lastSectionIndex];
```

Comment: Note that `NSInteger lastRowIndex = [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:lastSectionIndex] - 1;` will crash if the last section has 0 items.

Answer (score 3):

Answer for Swift 3

```
extension UICollectionView {

    func scrollToLastIndexPath(position:UICollectionViewScrollPosition, animated: Bool) {
        self.layoutIfNeeded()

        for sectionIndex in (0..<self.numberOfSections).reversed() {
            if self.numberOfItems(inSection: sectionIndex) > 0 {
                self.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath.init(item: self.numberOfItems(inSection: sectionIndex)-1, section: sectionIndex),
                                  at: position,
                                  animated: animated)
                break
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Note that my experience shows that `animated` property should be `false` for initializing the collectionView.

From the code above, as an answer to your question use this method:

```
func lastIndexPath() -> IndexPath? {
    for sectionIndex in (0..<self.numberOfSections).reversed() {
        if self.numberOfItems(inSection: sectionIndex) > 0 {
            return IndexPath.init(item: self.numberOfItems(inSection: sectionIndex)-1, section: sectionIndex)
        }
    }

    return nil
}
```